# If $\Bbb Q[x,y]$ is a field, are $x$ and $y$ algebraic over $\Bbb Q$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> If $x,y$ are two complex numbers, such that $\Bbb Q[x,y]$ is a field, then is it true that $x$ and $y$ algebraic over $\Bbb Q$?

I know that the converse is true, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362313/let-l-be-an-extension-field-of-k-and-let-%CE%B1-1-%CE%B1-n-%E2%88%88-l-be-algebraic-ove). This is true if I replace $\Bbb Q[x,y]$ by $\Bbb Q[x]$. This is wrong if I replace $\Bbb Q[x,y]$ by $\Bbb Q[x_1,x_2,\dots]$. For instance, similarly to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/856040/dimension-of-bbb-qe-over-bbb-q), I can complete $\{e\}$ into a countable $\mathbb Q$-basis $A$ of $\Bbb Q(e)$. Therefore, $\Bbb Q[e,a_1,a_2, \dots] = \Bbb Q(e)$ is a field.

If $x$ was not algebraic, maybe we could have $y=x^{-1}$. Then I should show that $x+y$ would have no inverse, for instance, but I'm stuck.

Comment: If $\mathbb F:\mathbb T:\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb F$ is algebraic over $\mathbb Q$, then...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is precisely the statement of Zariski's lemma: if $ K $ is a finitely generated algebra over a field $ k $ and $ K $ is a field, then $ K $ is a finite extension of $ k $. Clearly $ \mathbf Q[x, y] $ is finitely generated over $ \mathbf Q $. The condition that it is a field forces it to be a finite extension, and therefore both $ x $ and $ y $ are algebraic over $ \mathbf Q $.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Every field extension $L|K$ with $L$ finitely generated as a $K$-algebra is algebraic. This is a consequence of the Noether normalization lemma.

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain why this is a consequence of the Noether normalization lemma (I looked on Wikipedia what is stated). It seems more difficult than I expected.

Comment: By Noether normalization there is a $K$-subalgebra $R$ of $L$ such that $L|R$ is finite and $R$ is a polynomial algebra over $K$. You need now the fact that in an integral ring extension, if the ring upstairs is a field, so is the one downstairs. The extension $L|R$ is integral as it is finite, so $R$ is a field. As $R$ is a polynomial algebra, we must have $K = R$.