# Does $K[\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n]=K(\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n)$ imply $\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n$ are algebraic over $K$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I know how to prove that if $\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n$ are algebraic over $K$, then $K[\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n]$ is a field (i.e., $K[\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n]=K(\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n)$).

I also know the converse is true for $n=1$ and also know how to prove it.

However, I'm having real trouble to deal with the case $n\geq 2$.

I've tried to use the same strategy with $n=1$, which envolves the surjective homomorphism $\psi:K[X]\to K[\alpha]$ with $F \mapsto F(\alpha)$ and the fact that $K[X]$ is a principal ideal domain. But that doesn't work with a similar map $\psi:K[X_1, ..., X_n]\to K[\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n]$ since $K[X_1, ..., X_n]$ is not a principal domain.

I couldn't disprove it either. I tried to find a small example with $K=\mathbb{R}$ and $n=2$, but it also couldn't figure it out.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: This is a hard theorem, and is one of the ways to state the Nullstellensatz.

Comment: That is an interesting question. I didn't recognise it at first, but this is the Nullstellensatz, as Eric pointed out.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1898104

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. This follows from (or is essentially the content of) the Zariski lemma:  a finitely generated algebra over a field $k$ that is itself a field is finite over $k$.

You can find several proofs in these [notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/integral2015.pdf) by Pete Clark, around page 206.