# Does F[\alpha_1,\alpha_2] =F(\alpha_1,\alpha_2) imply \alpha_1,\alpha_2 are algebraic over F?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $F\subset L$ be a field extension, $\alpha_1, \cdots,\alpha_n \in L $. There is a theorem stating that, if $\alpha_1, \cdots,\alpha_n $ are algebraic over $L$, then $F(\alpha_1, \cdots,\alpha_n)=F[\alpha_1, \cdots ,\alpha_n]$. Moreover, when $n=1$, the converse is also true.

So, I want to know whether the converse is true when $n=2$? That is, Does $F[\alpha_1, \alpha_2] =F(\alpha_1, \alpha_2) $ imply $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$ are algebraic over $F$?

Comment: Consider one of the alphas (and denote it by $x$) as an indeterminate. Can $1/x$ now be written as a polynomial in all the alphas (including $x$)?

Comment: Thank you！ I found that this question have already been discussed here:[link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1898104/if-bbb-qx-y-is-a-field-are-x-and-y-algebraic-over-bbb-q?noredirect=1&lq=1) It is true as a corollary of Zariski's Lemma